# Jenkins picks wrong git binary

Tags: git, jenkins, server, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins server (version `2.150.2`) running on Oracle Linux `6.9`. Git `1.7.1` is installed on server and binary available under `/usr/bin/git` (shows upon running `which git` command).

My Windows slave is connected to this master and git is configured here as well. Still I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/git" (in directory "C:\Jenkins\workspace\x\y\z"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Tried upgrading all plugins and restarting Jenkins to no avail.

Somehow, the Jenkins git plugin is picking up the server git path instead of node. This is evident from console log:

```
...
15:17:07 Cloning the remote Git repository
15:17:08 Cloning repository xxx
15:17:09  > /usr/bin/git init C:\Jenkins\workspace\TestJobs\xxx\xxx # timeout=10
...
```

My Jenkins Git configurations:

- **Node (Windows)** Git mentioned under `Tool Locations`:

[image]

- **Server (Linux)** Git mentioned under `Global Tool Configuration`:

[image]

Comment: how are you runnng the git command in jenkins ? is it like /usr/bin/git ? or you are using the git plugin of jenkins ?

Comment: I am using the Jenkins git plugin

Comment: if you trying to run the jenkins job on the windows slave and it has git installed then check if the git path is added in the winodws PATH variable.

Aditionally also check if the windows slave tool configuration has anywhere git configurations hardcoded to /usr/bin/git

Comment: If I tell Jenkins specifically where to find the binary then why do I need to add it in PATH?

Comment: where are you defining that ? If you are runnning of windows slave the path /usr/bin/git doesnt exists

Comment: @yashbagarka I have edited the post to add more clarity

Comment: looks good ideally the local tool configurations of windows slave should be used but the default one of master is getting used. Can you check if there is any option in the job configuration for git executable. Also please attach the job configuration snap

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure Git tool in the **Manage Jenkins** -> **Manage Nodes** -> **YOUR_NODE_NAME** -> **Configure** page. In `Node Properties` section you must enable `Tool Locations` and then add Git tool location (you need to specify `Home` as for Git installed on your node).

Comment: I got the same issue and fixed it using the custom tool installation. Wonder whether it should be possible to specify a path per label pattern in the global tools locations, too.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I solved by choosing same names for Git installation in the "Global Tool Configuration" and the node's "Tool locations"

**Jenkins master Global Tool Configuration**

[image: Git name in master]

**Node Tool locations**

[image: Git name in node]

Very weird, but it works